# If Statement Inside Html

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to use an IF statement if variable `$credit` is not empty. However, I get a parse error. Could anyone please help with my syntax?

```
 $credit = get_field('fl_credit', $image['id']);
   return '<div class="kalim"><img title="' .
      esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . 
     '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) .
     '" src="' . $image['url'] . '" /><div class="kalca">' . 
     $image['caption'] . '</div>' . 
     if($credit) {'<div class="kalcr">Credit:' . $credit . '</div></div>' };
```

Comment: *What's* the parse error?

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string and a `if`. The `if` does not return a value. You need an expression such as ternary operator (.. ? .. : ) or a function that returns a value.

Comment: ok noted, I won't do this again but I believe my question is legitimate, why downvote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the error, I suggest do a short if, so:

```
 $credit = get_field('fl_credit', $image['id']);
   return '<div class="kalim"><img title="' .
      esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . 
     '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) .
     '" src="' . $image['url'] . '" /><div class="kalca">' . 
     $image['caption'] . '</div>' . 
     (!empty($credit) ? '<div class="kalcr">Credit:' . $credit . '</div></div>': '' ) ;
```

You can see more [here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)

Comment: Fun fact, this is called a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) :) - Also, you shouldn't post answers until you actually know what the issue is. This is easily a hole for downvotes if you are wrong.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton thanks for the clarification in both cases.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai if this works for you please mark it as answer.

Comment: I need to wait 2 more minutes as it doesn't let me do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it help you

```
<?php 
    $credit = get_field('fl_credit', $image['id']);
    $return_data = '<div class="kalim"><img title="'.esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" src="' . $image['url'] . '" /><div class="kalca">' . $image['caption'] . '</div>';
    if(!empty($credit)){
        $return_data .= '<div class="kalcr">Credit:' . $credit . '</div>';
    }
    $return_data .= '</div>';
    return $return_data;
?>
```